# OpenShift app - cannot see logs using rhc as admin collaborator

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am a collaborator on an OpenShift Online app with administrator privileges, and when I do `rhc apps` I can see the application, but when I do `rhc tail <appname>` I get `Application '<appname>' not found`.

Is there something I am missing?

Using `rhc` on Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"rhc apps" shows me the app that I am authorized to administer as a collaborator, however "rhc app stop" says - "app not found" 
`rhc -a app stop` gave me the usage help - `rhc app-stop <app> [--namespace NAME]`
which hinted that a namespace might be necessary for stopping an app in another domain where I am a collaborator

and `rhc app-stop testappname --namespace domainname` worked!

Answer (score 1):

Try appending your rhc commands with the -l option to specify a login.

Comment: Thanks for the response. rhc tail -l <email> -p <password> -a <appname> Did not work. Still get the application not found.